# Rolling Average Calculation per month - Dax Measure

Tags: dax, calculation, rolling-computation

I need to calculate ASMP which is Average Shipped per Month per Period.
Count of shipped / 12 (months in year), calculated each month or for period.
Count of records in a period on from table1, where 'ship_date' is not empty / divided by 12 (months in a year).
This is a rolling calculation. As the period length is increased, the count increases.
Example: Jan count is 5, Feb count is 6, Mar count is 2. If the calculation is executed in March, the sum is 13 / 12 = ASMP of 1.08. In April the count is 5, which increases the count. The ASMP for April is 1.5.

Any assistance on creating a calculation would be great

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

In PBI Desktop go to the *Modeling* tab and select *Quick measures*. Then in the *Calculation* dropdown select *Rolling average*, assign the *Base value* and *Date* fields and set *Period* to Months. That's all it needs!

Comment: Based on the poor description of the problem, the questioner cannot expect a more detailed answer.